# How to report progress from a different class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class which downloads information from a website.
I'm using the AsyncTask at the moment to get it, so the ui will stay responsive.

I understand how to update the GUI using the publishProgress and onProgessUpdate, but what if I have a big method (or function) within a different class?

It is easier to show with the code:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<Card> doInBackground(Void... voids)
{
    Looper.prepare();
    publishProgress("Creating object");
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
    publishProgress("Performing a long operation");
    ArrayList<Card> = someClass.getCards();//This method takes a long while. I would like to call the "publishProgress" method from the "someClass".

    return athopGetter.getCards();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the task reference to 'someClass', since publishProgress is protected final, you need to implement your own publish method, which simply invoke publishProgress,

```
task = new AsyncTask<...>() {
   ...
   public void myPublish(Progress... values) {
       publishProgress(values);
   } 
};
```

or you can use reflection to invoke publishProgress directly.